# I want to make JTextField part of checkbox or hook them together somehow

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, selection, jtextfield

I am making a Java application where I show a couple of checkboxes with relevant item from a file. Based on the selection I have to modify the original file accordingly. I have done this part.

I now realized that there might be some information that the user wants to add extra. I therefore want to show a checkbox with a JTextField hooked to it. The idea that I am trying to use is that if the value of checkbox is true, the value of JTextField associated with it, is included in the file.

I want to do something like this:

```
checkBoxes[i] = new Checkbox(new JTextField("enter new member e.g private int newMember"), null, false);
```

then

```
if(checkBoxes[i]==true)
{
    updatefile(file, checkBoxes[i]);
}
```

Where `updateFile` is a function that adds the value of `checkBoxes[i]` to file

Any idea on how should I work on this?

Comment: `checkBoxes[i]==true` indicates that this is a boolean, so how should `updatefile(file, checkBoxes[i]);` add anything to the file except `true`? Just create a data object that associates the checkbox' value with the textfield's value (or a compound component that contains a checkbox and a textfield).

Comment: Off-topic: I suggest you use JCheckBox since you also use JTextField. Swing and AWT don't always play nice together.

Comment: sorry i had to to write the value that the checkbox represents i.e label of checkbox. Also i tried using JCheckBox, it was causing an issue that the checkbox was hidden n got visible only when the mouse scolled over the area where checkboxes were added. i had written no code that would change the behaviour like this. so i had to revert to checkBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the `JTextField` separately, there's no need for them to be the same control.

i.e.

```
checkBoxes[i] = new JCheckBox("label");
textFields[i] = new JTextField("extra data");
// ...
if (checkBoxes[i].isSelected()) {
    updateFile(file, textFields[i]);
}
```

If you want to enable/disable the textFields based on the selected state of the checkbox, do it using a listener - e.g. an `ActionListener`:

```
checkBoxes[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        textFields[i].setEnabled(checkBoxes[i].isSelected());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have the `JTextField` as a seperate variable and have them both in a JPanel

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckbox("enter new member e.g private int newMember",false);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(checkBox);
panel.add(textField);
```

And then access it like that

```
if(checkBox.isSelected())
{
    updatefile(file, textField.getText());
}
```

Hope it helps.